# Get system path from rewritten URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

Given this rewritten URL as a string:

`/contact-us`

I would like to convert it to it's actual path, for example:

`/pages/contact/contact-us-page.aspx`

Is this possible?

Please note, I'm not asking how to re-write URL's, but how to convert a re-written path to it's actual file in code.

Comment: It probably depends on how you are rewriting the URLs.

Comment: @DavidG using `Intelligencia.UrlRewriter`